# Is it possible to extend the HttpClient.Timeout value for ML.NET's .AddPredictionEnginePool...FromUri() method?

Tags: c#, .net-5, ml.net

I have a .NET 5 Web API app that loads a few ML.NET model files via `AddPredictionEnginePool...FromUri()`, which of course is using `System.HttpClient` under the hood. The problem is, as far as I can tell, there's no way I can pass in my own instance of `HttpClient` with a timeout value higher than the default 100 seconds (it's a very large model zip file!).

Hopefully this is something that Microsoft's ML.NET team adds support for in the near-future, especially since it opens the door for potentially supporting some quirky authentication mechanisms in AWS and Azure. In the meantime, is there something else I can do to get around this problem, aside from using smaller model zip files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ML.NET but it looks like you can add data from a file. So you could just download the model using your own HttpClient, save it in a file and use this file in FromFile method.

Comment: Yes, FromFile rather than FromUri is an alternative, but I was hoping to be able to use FromUri since the app server is, well, serverless.

Comment: Ok then you can implement your own ModelLoader based on [UriModelLoader](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Extensions.ML/ModelLoaders/UriModelLoader.cs) with HttpClient that has longer timeout, and add it to services like in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/52ddbcd0a57b440e60e43e6cb39b49fe55bdfe55/src/Microsoft.Extensions.ML/Builder/BuilderExtensions.cs#L130).